# Ecto funny behavior in datetime?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I just found a funny behavior on Ecto when creating **inserted_at** and **updated_at**.

Before passed midnight, my app behaves normal.. but after passed midnight it behaves like below log

```
[info] >>> RUNTIME DATETIME {{2017, 7, 4}, {2, 38, 43}}
[info] >>> CHAT NEW = %Portal.DailyChat{__meta__: 
#Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "daily_chats">, id: 17, inserted_at: ~N[2017-07-03 19:38:43.315000], messages:
 "{\"chats\":[{\"time\":\"2:38:43\",\"message\":\"Test\",\"from\":\"bi***@gmail.com\"}]}", read: true, updated_at: ~N[2017-07-03 19:38:43.315000], user_a: %Po
rtal.User{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "users">, id: 3, inserted_at: ~N[2017-06-16 20:08:05.000000], name: "Indra", password: nil, password_
hash: "AF41E68E1309FA29A5044CBDC36B90A3821D8807E68C7675A6C495112BC8A55F", updated_at: ~N[2017-06-16 20:08:05.000000], username: "bi****@gmail.com"}, user_a_id:
 3, user_b: %Portal.User{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "users">, id: 1, inserted_at: ~N[2017-06-16 16:18:25.000000], name: "Bromo", passw
ord: nil, password_hash: "AF41E68E1309FA29A5044CBDC36B90A3821D8807E68C7675A6C495112BC8A55F", updated_at: ~N[2017-06-16 16:18:25.000000], username: "bro***@gm
ail.com"}, user_b_id: 1}
```

Value for **>>> RUNTIME DATETIME** is generated using **:calendar.local_time**, which produces a correct time.

For **>>> CHAT NEW** values is what **Ecto** generates after persisting data to DB, both **updated_at** and **inserted_at** are wrong time!

Does anybody knows how to fixed this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Read about the timestamps macro here: https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html I think you could either remove and replace it or customize its behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

The times aren't wrong, they're in UTC while `:calendar.local_time` returns the time in your system's timezone. Since there's a 7 hour difference, you probably live in one of [these places](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC%2B07:00).

If you run `:calendar.universal_time`, you should get the current UTC time, which will match the one Ecto used.

You can also convert the universal time to local time using `:calendar.universal_time_to_local_time/1` and the reverse using `:calendar.local_time_to_universal_time/1`.

Comment: Okay... how to force Ecto to use my local time then? any clue? So I can have the correct time in my record in DB

Comment: I just added how to convert universal time to local time. You should store the time in UTC and convert it when printing/showing to users.

Comment: Hmmm... that's a work around... not solving real issue... if I have another app using non elixir would be problem... if let say someone else doing it

Comment: Is there anyway I can manually set the value of both inserted_at and updated_at programmatically, instead of using Ecto auto generation?